# Add lwc component private property value in local storage when any of the field update via lightning record page (standard record detail component)

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, platform-event

After the record update having trigger handler logic to publish the PlatformEvent(PE) with required payload.. and each lightning record page have that PE subscriber LWC attached to make api callout in  response of the PE published. Here i'm able to send record Id and user Id with PE payload to filter the record for the user from different PE subscriber LWC. But handling duplicate tab opened by the same user for the same record require tracking of the record update(via lightning record page) triggered browser tab/window.

the idea is to check inside the handler logic, of the PE subscriber callback in lwc, if subscriber channelId returned in the PE payload(populated from sf session platform cache which stores the active lwc subscriber ids by userId and recordId as key) is current component subscriber id then only further logic to make api call via imperative apex call should run.

```js
      subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then(subscriptionInstance => {
        this.subscriptionInstance = subscriptionInstance;
        //create/add platform cache for the subscription id
        updateCache({ key: `${Id} ${this.recordId}`, subscriptionId: this.subscriptionInstance.id }).catch(console.error);
      });


      const messageCallback = (response) => {
          const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)),
            params = { recordId: obj.data.payload.RecordId__c?.split(' ')[1], requestType: obj.data.payload.Change_Type__c };
          if (params.recordId !== this.recordId || Id !== obj.data.payload.RecordId__c?.split(' ')[0] || this.subscriptionInstance.id !== params.requestType.split(' ')[1] **will add the current subscriber check here**) return;
          window.clearTimeout(this.timer);
          this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            updateThirdParty(params).then(response => {
              const result = JSON.parse(response || {});
              if (result?.data?.apiError || result?.data.errors?.length) {// toast errors
              } 
            })
              .catch(error => {
                this.showToast('Something went wrong', error.body.message, 'error')
              })
          }, DEBOUNCE_TIME);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('error >>>>>> ', error);
        }
      };
```

please suggest if you have any other best approach to fix the problem..

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I get your question. E.g. what has the local storage to do with the problem of setting up the platform event subscriber? In any case it would make it much easier to answer, if you added some of your source code (which apparently creates the Platform Event) to your question.

Comment: hi @FelixvanHove thanks to look into this, see now i have added the description to be more clear